# How to fetch email thread by messageId using IMAP in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, imap, nodemailer

I want to fetch whole reply thread using the particular **messageId** something like this `2a2b0f84-261c-ecd5-33bf-919548b76000@hotmail.com`.

I have tried this:

```
    const getInbox = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {
            return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
                var searchCriteria = ['ALL'];
                var fetchOptions = {
                    bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT', ''],
                };
                return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(async function (messages) {
                    let promises = messages.map(item=>{
                        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                            var all = _.find(item.parts, { "which": "" })
                            var id = item.attributes.uid;
                            var idHeader = "Imap-Id: " + id + "\r\n";
                            simpleParser(idHeader + all.body, (err, mail) => {
                                resolve(mail);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    Promise.all(promises).then(data=>{
                        let d = data.filter(obj=>obj.me).map(obj=>{
                            return {
                                from:obj.from.value.map(obj=>obj.address).join(','),
                                to:obj.to.value.map(obj=>obj.address).join(','),
                                subject:obj.subject,
                                attachments:obj.attachments,
                                message_id:obj.messageId,
                                date:obj.date

                            }
                        });
                        resolve(d);
                    })
                });
            });
        });
    }); }
```

I have tried this , it is returning whole inbox, I want particular message thread.

Comment: Did you forget to put the message id into your code?  HEADER TEXT ""  looks like a good way to get every message in the mailbox.

Comment: can you tell me how to specify messageId in search criteria ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this

```
var searchCriteria = [['HEADER','IN-REPLY-TO',messageId]];
```

it is working perfectly.

Comment: IIRC that is supposed to match direct replies, but not replies to replies.

Comment: How can I get replies to replies ?

Comment: As in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57578147) above.

Comment: As I used that solution im getting " Error: Unexpected search option: OR HEADER "MESSAGE-ID" "895C473F-E9E5-47FF-C498-5E28A6692EDF@ZIBTEK.IN" HEADER "REFERENCES" "895C473F-E9E5-47FF-C498-5E28A6692EDF@ZIBTEK.IN""

Comment: I tested it just now, and that search key is valid. The full command I used was `x search OR HEADER "MESSAGE-ID" "895C473F-E9E5-47FF-C498-5E28A6692EDF@ZIBTEK.IN" HEADER "REFERENCES" "895C473F-E9E5-47FF-C498-5E28A6692EDF@ZIBTEK.IN"`. You have to pay attention to spaces and punctation, IMAP is a strict protocol, not a lax one.

Comment: searchCriteria expecting in array format.Can you please send me the array form of searchCriteria

Comment: something like this   `var searchCriteria = ['OR HEADER "Message-ID" "' + id + '" HEADER "References" "' + id + '"'];`

Comment: @arnt searchCriteria expecting in array format.Can you please send me the array form of searchCriteria,something like this `var searchCriteria = ['OR HEADER "Message-ID" "' + id + '" HEADER "References" "' + id + '"'];`

Answer (score 1):

This line in your code means to search for all messages:

```
            var searchCriteria = ['ALL'];
```

Really quite clear code, don't you agree? If you try something more like

```
            var searchCriteria = ['OR HEADER "Message-ID" "' + id + '" HEADER "References" "' + id + '"'];
```

then you'll search for just the messages you want, and then you can retrieve their headers and bodies and do whatever you want.

Comment: for Gmail and Hotmail, it is working perfectly but for yahoo, it is not working, it throwes "UID SEARCH Server error - Please try again later".

Comment: Might want to turn on debugging and get a protocol log of that. "Please try again later" doesn't sound as if there's anything wrong in your code, more like a load problem on the server. But get a protocol log.

Comment: @AbdulMohaimin can you please send me the complete script please. I need to search by message-id using node-imap npm package.